# Monotouch lazyload UIScrollView

Tags: c#, iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

In my application I have a UIScrollView that will load many very large images. I don't want to load all of them same time. Is it possible to load the images a few at a time so that everytime the user scrolls a couple more get added (and the ones that have already been scrolled are removed).

I really can't find anything online on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

shahzad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this on demand, and load the image only when needed.

There are a few ways of doing this, the simplest is to hook up to the Scrolled event in the UIScrollView, and load the images on demand.